# Correct solution to use the System default button when using MaterialDesignTheme WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to use `System` default button when using [MaterialDesign WPF](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) but I am a little worried.

I want to use 2 types of buttons simultaneously in the same window.

I used the `Style` and used `StaticResource` but I am not sure that is a correct solution.

**Step 1: Create a Style:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Step 2: Use:**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" 
        Name="btnChange" 
        Content="My Button Style" 
        Height="35" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Margin="10"></Button>
```

> The `MaterialDesign` **Style** will be not applied on this `Button`.

Is this a correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct but if you want to change all of your buttons in your `View` or `Software` you should do this in your View's `Resource` or `App.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

and you don't need to use `StaticResource`.

But if you want to have some different style of buttons you should do this:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

And you should use `StaticResource`.

And if your button's style is equal but these have a little difference you can create a base button style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <!-- ... -->
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonBaseStyle}">
     <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```